# How can I control my two AC motors from a single 3-conductor relay?

Tags: ac, relay, actuator

[image]

I have a pool system that can control two valve actuators via relays, one to switch the water return from either the pool or spa, and another to feed filtered water to either the pool or spa. Each valve actuator is a 24vac motor with three conductors. The common conductor providing 24vac, and the switch legs representing FWD and REV directions on the actuator.

I can trivially control a single actuator as I have 3 conductors running from my relay to my valves, however, I need 6 conductors in order to *properly* control both. Unfortunately, I do not currently have 6 conductors, and the cost of running additional wire is not insignificant.

This afternoon I had the idea of merely splitting the connections and feeding both actuators. I tested it out, and it worked, sort of. What I observed was strange behavior when one actuator completed before the other, in which that actuator would move erratically until the other reached its final point. What I measured is that the non-active switch leg (i.e., REV when FWD is selected from the relay) is active while the actuators are in motion, despite being disconnected at the relay. My understanding is that there is a capacitor in the actuator to phase-shift the AC signal. The relay doesn't care about said backfeed, but trying to bridge the two motors in this way seems like it could damage them.

Is there some sort of way, using only these three conductors, and the corresponding switch from FWD to REV via the relay, to properly control the two actuators?

If it helps, here's information about the motor itself:
[image]

Thanks! And sorry if I'm not using the proper terms.

Comment: Get an extra relay for one of the actuators and use the 'primary' relay to control the new relay in addition to the other actuator.

Comment: @brhans will you say more about how to actually accomplish that given the inputs?